# PlaySound() Lags opengl c++

Tags: c++, sound, winapi

I am new to OpenGL. I am making a game similar to this, shown in image below. The problem is when I detect collision, i.e cannon ball and ship collide, I play a sound using

```
PlaySound(TEXT("explode.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
```

After the sound is played, my background animation and the whole scene is stuck for a second and then it resumes. Any fix? Please help. It is my project.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation of PlaySound() on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx) it states:

> The **SND_ASYNC** flag causes **PlaySound** to return immediately without waiting for the sound to finish playing.

The conclusion from this information, although not explicitly stated there, is that PlaySound() waits for the sound to finish playing, if the **SND_ASYNC** flag is *not* specified. Therefore the lag you experience when playing a sound has not to do with OpenGL but with the fact that PlaySound() just waits for the sound to finish before it returns, thus blocking the calling thread.

So the proper code for non-blocking (i.e. asynchronous) sound should be:

```
PlaySound(TEXT("explode.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
```

If you want to stop an asynchronous sound before it is finished, use

```
PlaySound(NULL, 0, 0);
```

Comment: in my init() there is PlaySound(TEXT("ocean.wav"), NULL, SND_ASYNC | SND_LOOP); , so when i play explode sound i.e PlaySound(TEXT("explode.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);  , the looping sound is finished, is there any way to keep it going ?

Comment: There surely is a way, but probably not with `PlaySound` only, because `PlaySound` seems to be a rather primitive function that is not very helpful, if you want to manage several sounds playing simultaneously. Maybe you should look for other means to manage the sound. Perhaps [OpenAL](https://www.openal.org/) is an option for you?